# Spring Data JPA repository method with property name containing a special word

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

For example, I have an entity with the following attribute:

```
@Entity
public class MyObj {
    public String nameOrId;
}
```

I then proceed to create the repository

```
public interface MyObjRepository extends JpaRepository<MyObj, String> {
    MyObj findByNameOrId(String nameOrId);
}
```

This fails, because it seems that Spring tokenizes the method name as `findBy` `Name` `Or` `Id`, instead of `findBy` `nameOrId`.

The resulting error is "name" property not found (or similar).

Is there a way to escape the special words ("Or", "And", etc) in the method syntax? Renaming the column to not include those words is not an option.

Comment: I'm not sure you can escape that kind of special words in your method syntax. You'll probably have to add an `@Query` annotation on top of your method to give the JpaRepository the query you want to execute

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A workaround is to rename the Java field to avoid special words, while preserving the column name using the `@Column` annotation.

```
@Column(name = "nameOrId")
public String nameId;
```

The JPA method is renamed accordingly.

```
MyObj findByNameId(String nameOrId);
```