# MongoRepository Query for Attribute having "Or" in it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mongorepository

I am querying my MongoDB using MongoRepository. Assume my DB contains data as follows:

```
{
    stateOrCountry:"SomeValue"
}
```

Now if I write Query like

```
findByStateOrCountry("country")
```

It thinks that I am searching either for the state or country.
How to write a query for keys which have "Or" in them

Comment: Duplication , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213353/spring-data-jpa-repository-method-with-property-name-containing-a-special-word

Comment: use something like this @Column(name = "stateOrCountry")
public String statecountry;

Comment: I cant change the field Name as suggested in other post @Anil

Comment: did you tried running above methods, what error it is throwing?

Comment: if that does not work use @Query